# Is it possible to trap first the values of my form and saving it to my database before i will redirect my customer to paypal?

Tags: cakephp, paypal

Here's what i have. I want to trap these values before handing the customer over to paypal. This is for the purpose of saving the shipping address and email provided by the customer in my form:

```
<?php $countries = array(
       'af' => 'Afganistan', 
       'al' => 'Albania', 
       //... 
       'zm' => 'Zambia', 
       'zw' => 'Zimbabwe' 
); ?>

<div class="section">
    <h3>Customer Details</h3>
    <hr />
    <div class="user-form">
        <div class="user-header">Personal Info</div>
        <div class="user-section showBorder">
            <label>Full Name:</label>
            <?php echo $this->Form->input('fullname',array('label'=>false, 'class'=>'user-field'));?>
            <label>Contact Number:</label>
            <?php echo $this->Form->input('contactnumber',array('label'=>false, 'class'=>'user-field'));?>
            <label>Email:</label>
            <?php echo $this->Form->input('email',array('label'=>false, 'class'=>'user-field'));?>
        </div>
        <div class="user-header">Delivery Address</div>
        <div class="user-section showBorder">
            <label>Address Line 1</label>
            <?php echo $this->Form->input('address1',array('label'=>false, 'class'=>'user-field'));?>
            <label>Address Line 2</label>
            <?php echo $this->Form->input('address1',array('label'=>false, 'class'=>'user-field'));?>
            <label>City</label>
            <?php echo $this->Form->input('city',array('label'=>false, 'class'=>'user-field'));?>
            <label>State/Province/Region:</label>
            <?php echo $this->Form->input('state',array('label'=>false, 'class'=>'user-field'));?>
            <label>Zip Code:</label>
            <?php echo $this->Form->input('zip',array('label'=>false, 'class'=>'user-field'));?>
            <label>Country: </label>
            <div>
                <?php echo $this->Form->select('country',$countries,array('label'=>false, 'class'=>'user-select'));?>
            </div>
        </div>
        <div class="user-submit">
            <?php echo $this->Form->submit('Ship to other Address',array('class'=>'customButton'));?>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

is it possible to do it that way or IPN can help me save those data in my database?

Answer (score 0):

How are you capturing the IPN callback?

IPN will return the data supplied by the customer - I'm not 100% sure, but I believe if you ask the user for shipping information they will be asked again in the PayPal form - you might need to refer to the PayPal documentation to turn off these fields?

If you save that form data, there is no reason you cannot just pick the fields out of the IPN return data and update your own record?

I would still keep the full IPN callback in a model somewhere and link it to your customer/order record as it's essentially transaction data.

Comment: meaning to say, that i can turn off those fields and use my own form in saving those data and letting IPN help me capture the data in my form? I am not yet capturing any data in ipn coz im really lost where am i going to put the capturing code and what i am going to code in it. It is indicated in the tutorial that paypal sends IPN variables via post method.. and then, i dunno what to do next and where to do it  >.<

Comment: Charmie.. I have seen some of your other posts about Paypal IPN & CakePHP. I really recommend you go and spend some time researching how IPN works before trying to integrate it into your project.

Comment: yep.. im trying even more...  >.<  i guess im just frustrated doing this for 3days now.. somebody told me that i can capture those values thru a controller and let the payment be handled by paypal... if that is the case, then i will be facing a different problem then since i provided the shipping address of the customer, what will happen if there is a different shipping address specified in the database of paypal.. i'll be researching more...